# Build Simple UI Lesson Sample

Tags: android

Ok, I have been following a lesson sample at the Android Developer site and the code was thus:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Apparently, the code should be fine, after worrying I typed it in wrong, I ended up copying it directly but the Console is telling me:

Description 
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/edit_message').

Description 
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/button_send').

Now these values are defined in the strings.xml file. So I have no idea why I would be getting these errors.

To anyone who can help here is a big thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you saved `strings.xml`, saved your layout, and then cleaned the project (if necessary)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure there is no capital characters or underscores in any file inside res.
Also , there must no any error inside the files of res and src .. 
after that you have to clean the project as mentioned in previous answer.
Actually these errors prevent the R file to be updated which is necessary to access resources inside res file.

Comment: Found that out the hard way :)  Thanks for telling me why though.

Answer (score 1):

Try in eclipse project>clean . Sometimes eclipse give you errors like these. Or restart eclipse. Did you also make sure at your strings.xml you have something like this ?
`<string name="edit_message">Your intresting string.</string>` sometimes if you use the 'gui resource adder' It gives mistakes. Check inside your xml.

Comment: And does it work? Did you make sure you don't have errors in your other xmls?

Comment: Oops sorry, tried editing the answer ran out of time ...    Ok tried: cleaning the file, restarting Eclipse.  And when I rechecked the "strings.xml" file those two variables had disappeared!!!  So I put them back in and the errors went - it's possible that in my haste I forgot to save the file.  Although I know I did!

Comment: Always use control+shiflt+s , this is save all files. If you found the answer useful please click the check mark next to this answer for others to see if they have teh same problem.